# SSRS Report resizes when rendered in preview mode

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I created a report in Visual Studio 2012 and am having issues with the report resizing when I try to print it to pdf or view in print layout. I sent the .rdl to others on my team and they printed it to pdf with no issues.

I tried adjusting the margins, page size, interactive size, as well as turning ConsumeAllwhitespace=true. I also installed all updates and nothing seems to correct the issue. Any suggestions?

- Page Size: 8.5"x 11"
- Margins: 0.25",0.25",0.25",0.25"
- Interactive Size: 8.5"x 11"
- Body: 8", 4.15"

Example:
[image: Print preview showing added whitespace to bottom and right of report]

Comment: the format is always a issue, did you check the `Cangrow` properties in both height and weight?

Comment: What do you mean the report is re-sizing?  I assume you mean it is spilling over the page, causing blank pages to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `CanGrow` properties to false from the report `properties` page

Comment: Thanks for the response but this did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.

First set your Margins to .5in". I have tested this and this is the smallest your margins can be for your report to print correctly.

Next drag your report right border to just under 7.5" (just to where that half inch hash mark is not visible). Make sure you drag your table content to fill white space.

If you're still having issues in your print dialog, check the PDF print settings. Open a PDF and go to the print dialog. Under **Page Size & Handling** there are FIT, ACTUAL SIZE, SHRINK, and CUSTOM SCALE. Custom Scale at 100% will guarantee the PDF will print at the correct size. Whatever setting you set here seems to apply to all PDF print dialogs.

If that doesn't work, try using Report Builder. Less frills but always works right!

Comment: Margins can be smaller than .5 in.  I rarely use a margin larger than .25 in any of my reports and have gone down to .1 .  I think the minimum margin depends more on the capability of your physical printer, but when outputting to PDF, you can use any margin value.

Comment: Check that you are not using a mix of measure units. I regularly encountered reports with a page size in inches and column/row sizes in cm. When rendered, the report would be the wrong size (but no apparent logig to the rendered size)

Comment: I stand corrected! None of the printers here at my company work on less than .5". I was trying to get a stripe to go all the way across the page. No dice.

Comment: I'm just going to reinstall visual studio. Nothing seems to be fixing the issue. Thanks though.